# Edubuntu LTSP amd64 not Loading with PXE

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, edubuntu, ltsp

I have a computer lab running off of an i386 fat-client image right now. The image is being hosted via LTSP on Edubuntu 14.04.1 LTS with the client being the same desktop. However, the package system on this client image is broken due to a non-PAE kernel (?) not being able to upgrade. The kernel thing is separate, but this is the reason why I am switching to amd64 instead of just sticking with i386.

I have added an amd64 fat-client image now. However, my HP Compaq dc7800 Small Form Factor clients are still booting the i386 without asking which one to boot. In addition, if I move the i386 prefix, the pxe client refuses to look for amd64. I know for sure the processors are 64-bit, so I am confused as to what the issue is.

The LTSP server is 64-bit and is mostly running with default settings.

Help (of any kind) is appreciated. If this is a duplicate, I would be grateful to be pointed in the right direction as I've been searching for hours now with no luck. If any more info, files, etc. are needed, just let me know and I'll update the post. Thanks!

Comment: Is this question too awkwardly written? Or is this just such a niche application of Ubuntu, there are few experts? It's kind of weird that I haven't gotten so much as a comment, even when I had placed a bounty on the question.

Comment: Sounds like your tftpd is pointing to your i386 image. Have a look at tftp option 67.

Comment: Ok... that's a starting point. Unfortunately I have no idea what that means or how to do this. Is this on the client side or server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a year and a half of trying to figure this out (off and on, of course), I finally have an answer. (And, I'm frankly a little embarrassed by how long it took). All that needs to be done is edit the file at `/etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf`. Here's a copy of the new file to those who may be interested (you'll notice the mentions to i386 commented out and amd64 put in its place):

```
# Default LTSP dhcpd.conf config file.
#

authoritative;

subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.0.20 192.168.0.250;
    option domain-name "example.com";
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.1;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
    option routers 192.168.0.1;
#    next-server 192.168.0.1;
#    get-lease-hostnames true;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
#    option root-path "/opt/ltsp/i386";
    option root-path "/opt/ltsp/amd64";
    if substring( option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 9 ) = "PXEClient" {
#        filename "/ltsp/i386/pxelinux.0";
        filename "/ltsp/amd64/pxelinux.0";
    } else {
#        filename "/ltsp/i386/nbi.img";
        filename "/ltsp/amd64/nbi.img";
    }
}
```